# What wildcard UBlock Origin should I use to block these elements?

Tags: adblock

What wildcard should I use to block all elements of this type with any number? Whether it's 50, 500 or 9999999 and etc. Here are the elements:

```
example.com###ad-row-1
example.com###ad-row-2
example.com###ad-row-3
```

Comment: have you tried to use wildcard `*` like `example.com###ad-row-*`? https://help.eyeo.com/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters

Comment: yes i tried. it doesn't work